# Syntax for binomial formula in geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have computed a binomial regression in R:

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(success, failure) ~ x * f, family = "binomial", 
    data = tb1)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.6195  -0.9399  -0.0493   0.5698   2.0677  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.3170182  0.0622600 -37.215  < 2e-16 ***
x            0.0138201  0.0009892  13.972  < 2e-16 ***
fTRUE        0.6466238  0.1976115   3.272  0.00107 ** 
x:fTRUE     -0.0035741  0.0032587  -1.097  0.27273    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 479.88  on 147  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 201.53  on 144  degrees of freedom
  (7 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 870.72

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

and I'd like to visualize it. I would like to plot the data and the regression curve. I can easily get the linear smoother to work:

```
ggplot(tb1, aes(x, success/(success+failure), colour=f)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image: Linear Regression]

but what I really want is to draw a logistic curve through the data. When I try:

```
ggplot(tb1, aes(x, success/(success+failure), colour=f)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    method="glm",
    method.args=list(family="binomial"),
  )
```

I get this graph:

[image: Suspicious binomial regression]

which doesn't seem right. The standard errors shouldn't be so large. I thought I'd need to specify the formula explicitly in geom_smooth, but I can't get the syntax right. When I try

```
ggplot(tb1, aes(x, success/(success+failure), colour=f)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    method="glm",
    method.args=list(
      family="binomial",
      formula = cbind(success, failure) ~ x
    )
  )
```

I get

> Warning message:
>   Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
>   object 'success' not found

How do I specify the formula correctly?

Comment: Seems the formula only knows about x and y which are presumably inferred from the aesthetics?

Comment: @NelsonGon: Thanks, you seem to be right. However, Now I get the warning: "In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!"

Comment: This is statistical I guess. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap/issues/16).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As in binomial regression, the formula in `geom_smooth` needs to have a matrix of successes and failures as the response. The corresponding variables need to be defined in the aesthetics:

```
ggplot(tb1, aes(x, y=success/(success+failure), colour=f, succ=success, fail=failure)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    method="glm",
    method.args=list(family="binomial"),
    formula = cbind(succ, fail) ~ x
  )
```

Now it works:

[image: Correct binomial smoothing]

Thanks to [NelsonGon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10323798/nelsongon) for pointing this out.